# Is the Goldbach conjecture easier if we allow 1 as a prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, open-problems, goldbach-type-problems

I hope this is the right site for the question.

Is the Goldbach conjecture easier if we allow 1 as a prime? (12=1+11 would be allowed as Goldbach sum for 12)

IOW: if we can prove Goldbach for the case 1 is a prime number, can we then prove it for the standard case?

Comment: To reformulate your reformulation, you are asking if it is known that standard Goldbach holds for numbers of the form $p + 1$ for $p$ an (odd) prime.

Comment: Once we have a prove, we'll know. Until then...

Comment: @LSpice
Well, we don't have any counterexample to Goldbach. I just thought there is a proof for the equivalence of both problems; because in the standard case, nowadays, we don't allow it, but at the time of Goldbach and Euler: 1 was a prime number.

Comment: @LSpice: maybe you mean: ...for $p$ a **composite** (odd) number  ?

Comment: @PietroMajer, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1134682), what I [meant](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1134678) was: if "Goldbach+1" holds but Goldbach doesn't, and if $n$ is a counterexample to Goldbach, then (by "Goldbach+1") $n$ equals $a + b$ for $(a, b) \in (P \cup \{1\})^2 \setminus P^2$; so one of $a$ or $b$, but not both since Goldbach excludes $n = 2$, is $1$; so $n$ is of the form $p + 1$ for $p \in P$.  So proving "Goldbach+1" reduces the proof of Goldbach to handling even $n \in P + 1$.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439892/is-the-goldbach-conjecture-easier-if-we-allow-1-as-a-prime#comment1134681_439892), according to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture#History), Goldbach actually stated "Goldbach+1".  And the author of that article makes the same [observation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439892/is-the-goldbach-conjecture-easier-if-we-allow-1-as-a-prime#comment1134697_439892), but does not know, or at least does not mention, any proof that Goldbach follows from "Goldbach+1".

Comment: (ok, so this is the reformulation of OP's question 2, while question 1 is about "Goldbach+1", which is equivalent to standard Goldbach for even numbers not of the form 1+p)